# Increase padding in Cygwin

Tags: terminal, cygwin

I followed along [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115762/increase-padding-in-gnome-terminal)(Makaze's answer) to change the padding of my Ubuntu terminal.
And now that I have successfully done that, I can't seem to work from cygwin, as, compared to my ubuntu terminal now it seems awkward.

Is there any way I can change(i.e increase) the padding in cygwin?
There is no `.config` folder to begin with.